# Series representation of measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I need to show that if a positive function $f$ on $E$, where $(E,\mathcal{E})$ is a measurable space, is $\mathcal{E}$-measurable then it has the form
$$f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n1_{A_n},$$
for some sequence $(a_n)\subset \bar{\mathbb{R}}_{+}$ and some sequence $(A_n)\subset \mathcal{E}$ (not necessarily disjoint).

Since $f$ is measurable and positive it is a pointwise limit of an increasing sequence of positive simple functions, that is
$$f(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^ka_{n,k}1_{B_{n,k}}(x),\ \forall x\in E,$$
where for all $k$ we can assume $(B_{n,k})_{1\leq n\leq k}\subset \mathcal{E}$ are pairwise disjoint. I'm having trouble understanding what $a_n$'s and $A_n$'s should be since I think that $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n,k}$ need not exist (the sets $B_{n,k}$ and $B_{n,k+1}$ can be disjoint).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, note that it suffices to consider the case that $0 \leq f \leq 1$. *Indeed*: Suppose that the claim holds for any measurable $f$ such that $0 \leq f \leq 1$. Let $g$ be an arbitrary non-negative function. We can write

$$g = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 1_{\{k \leq g < k+1\}} \cdot g.$$

Then $0 \leq (g -k) 1_{\{k \leq g < k+1\}} \leq 1$ and we have (by assumption) an representation of the form

$$(g-k) 1_{\{k \leq g < k+1\}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n,k} 1_{A_{n,k}}.$$

Thus,

$$g 1_{\{k \leq g < k+1\}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n,k} 1_{A_{n,k}} + k 1_{\{k \leq g < k+1\}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n,k} 1_{A_{n,k}}$$

if we set $a_{0,k} = k$ and $A_{0,k} = \{k \leq g < k+1\}$. Finally, we conclude

$$g = \sum_{k \geq 0} g 1_{\{k \leq g < k+1\}} = \sum_{k \geq 0} \sum_{n \geq 0} (a_{n,k}+k) 1_{A_{n,k}}.$$

---

It remains to prove the claim for measurable $f$ such that $0 \leq f \leq 1$. By the Sombrero lemma, there exists a simple function $g_1$ such that $0 \leq f-g_1\leq \frac{1}{2}$. Note that $f-g_1$ is again a non-negative (measurable) function and therefore, we can choose a simple function $g_2$ such that $0 \leq (f-g_1)-g_2 \leq \frac{1}{2^2}$. Iterating this procedure we find a sequence $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of simple functions satisfying

$$0 \leq f - \sum_{j=1}^k g_j \leq \frac{1}{2^k}.$$

This proves in particular $f = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} g_j$. On the other hand, it is clear that for each $j \in \mathbb{N}$ we can write

$$g_j = \sum_{i=1}^{N(j)} a_{i,j} 1_{A_{i,j}}.$$

Consequently,

$$f = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} g_j = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{N(j)} a_{i,j} 1_{A_{i,j}}.$$

This yields the desired representation for $f$.

---

> **Sombrero lemma:** Let $(E,\mathcal{A})$ be measurable space and $f: E \to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative mesasurable function. Then there exists a sequence of simple functions $(f_n)_n$ such that $0 \leq f_n \leq f$ and $f_n \uparrow f$. If $f$ is bounded, the convergence is uniformly.

*Proof:* For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we define

$$f_n(x) := \begin{cases} k 2^{-n}, & \text{if} \, x \in \{k 2^{-n} \leq f < (k+1) 2^n\} \, \text{for some} \, k \in \{0,\ldots,2^{2n}\} \\  2^n, & \text{otherwise}, \end{cases}$$

so, basically, $f_n(x) = k 2^{-n}$ if $f(x) \in [k 2^{-n},(k+1) 2^{-n})$. Obviously, $f_n$ is a simple function, $f_n \leq f$ and $f_n \uparrow f$. If $f$ is bounded, then we have

$$f_n(x) := \begin{cases} k 2^{-n}, & x \in \{k 2^{-n} \leq f < (k+1) 2^n\} \, \text{for some} \, k \in \{0,\ldots,2^{2n}\}  \end{cases}$$

for $n$ sufficiently large. In particular, $0 \leq f(x)-f_n(x) \leq 2^{-n}$ for any $x \in E$. This shows the uniform convergence.

Literature: *René L. Schilling: Measures, integrals and martingales. Cambridge University Press, 2011.*

Comment: I think the $f$'s in your first summation should be $g$'s?

Comment: @Bungo You are right; thanks.

Comment: It's a nice proof, but the key is this Sombrero's lemma you mentioned. I haven't heard of it, nor did I find any references to it using google, except in a few other MSE postings of yours :-) I think it suffices to define $g_1(x)$ to be $0$ if $f(x) \leq 1/2$ and $1/2$ if $f(x) > 1/2$, right? Then $g_1$ is simple because it is a scalar multiple of a characteristic function of a measurable set.

Comment: @Bungo That's exactly the idea. However, since you mention that the result is not (well)known, I'll add the general statement to my answer (but not right now, there is some work to be done :/ ...). A reference is the monograph by René Schilling, "Measures, Integrals and Martingales".

Comment: @nokiddn Yeah, sorry, we have to multiply $f_k$ with the indicator function $1_{\{k \leq g < k+1\}}$; see edit.

Comment: @nokiddn Argh... what a mess. Sorry, I did it the wrong way round.

Comment: @saz It looks fine now, thanks. I was also wondering why the last expression is what we actually want, but I think it's because we can change a double series to a single series by renaming the sets ant sequences, right?

Comment: @saz Btw, the same thing can be achieved using the fact that $g = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} g_k$ where $g_k$ is bounded, thus there's a sequence of simple functions $(g_{n,k})$ converging to $g_k$ *uniformly* and the rest is the same as in the second part of your proof.

Comment: @nokiddn Yes, we can rename the sequence in order to obtain a single series.

Comment: @Bungo I have just added the statement (+proof).

Comment: @saz: Thanks for the reference. I knew the result, but not by that name, and it's nice to have the proof as part of your answer since it's the key component.